# Getting the values of the link using get variable in php

Tags: php, sql, get

I have a link in a php file which takes mke to another page. Here is the link:

```
 <?php  echo ' <a href="product_detail.php?marca='.$row["maname"].'">'?>
```

So I know that I can take the marca from this link using $_GET["marca"] in php.
Now I want to output some categories   but only them which marca is the same as $_GET["marca"]. I create this sql query but it outputs an error in the last row:

```html
$sql0="SELECT  marche.marca as maname 
FROM marche
 WHERE maname=$_GET["marca"];
  ";
```

Have I done something wrong? Can someone tell me which is the right syntax to include get variable inside sql queries?Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be okay except at one place.

```
$sql0="SELECT marche.marca as maname FROM marche WHERE maname=".$_GET["marca"];
```

But you should not depend on input ,you need to first sanitize it.
e.g.,

```
$input = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET["marca"]));

$sql0="SELECT marche.marca as maname FROM marche WHERE maname='$input'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you try de put php in your request, you need to close the SQL request, do your action in php, then open again your SQL request, like that :

```
$sql0="SELECT marche.marca as maname 
FROM marche 
WHERE maname=" . $_GET["marca"] .";";
```